# How do i add a socket?

Tags: socket

[image]

Hi, I would be grateful to receive advice on my proposed way of adding a socket from bath 1 to bath 2 by tapping on bath 2's existing socket (i plan to tie the new set of wires in with socket A's wires in its L,N & E grooves and run along d existing cable channels to the other side of the wall n attach a new socket). Am I right to do it this way? Are there anything else I should take note? I planned to install a IP66 socket.

Comment: There is a rule restricting electrical receptacles in bathrooms in the UK;  they have to be some rather large distance from a tub or shower or maybe even a lavatory. Is the IP66 an exception to the general rule?

Comment: Does the circuit serve any other loads besides that bathroom receptacle?

Comment: Yes, the circuit serves 4 other single gang 13A socket and 1 double gang 13A socket.